# Rails checkbox not saving any value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I am new to Rails and I have these checkboxes that display the options just fine, but aren't changing anything in the database as the form is submitted.
The form in views has the following piece of code:

```
<%= form_for(@sector) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :admins_id, Admin.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

and this is the corresponding action in the sectors controller:

```
def update
  @sector = Sector.find(params[:id])
  @sector.admins_id = params[:admins_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @sector.update(sector_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @sector, notice: 'Sector was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @sector }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @sector.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
private
  def sector_params
    params.require(:sector).permit(:title, :admins_id)
  end
```

And, finally, I have these relations in the models:

```
class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admins, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
end
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sector
end
```

Also, I can create and assign admins just fine in the rails console.

Comment: Based on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes, can you try `f.collection_check_boxes :admin_ids, Admin.all, :id, :name`. Notice its `ids` not `id`

Comment: Check for strong parameter problems too: http://makandracards.com/makandra/32147-rails-4-introduced-collection_check_boxes

Comment: I think you actually don't receive anything with  `:admins_id`. Params what you get from `form_for` method is `:sector`, where   `:admins_id` is nested. Try `params[:sector][:admins_id]`.

Comment: tried all of above. Nothing worked. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Then you should provide rails logs on what happens when you try submit checkbox @Haken

Comment: Also I suggest you to read [rails debugging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting a single **admins_id** then you don't need check boxes (which will pass through an array of ids) use collection_radio_buttons (for a single id) instead.

However, if you want to set multiple admins through the has_many association, then keep the checkboxes, but change the attribute name to be **admin_ids**. (Don't forget to change the name in the permit() whitelist as well).

Also, you can remove this line:

```
@sector.admins_id = params[:admins_id]
```

It's not necessary because it is set through the update().

Comment: But I'm not setting a single admins_id, as you can also see in the models. Thanks nonetheless.